# Getting a users likes in Soundcloud Widget API

Tags: iframe, soundcloud

I'm trying to create a widget which tracks and plays tracks a specified user has like.

I understand (or atleast think) there is an option to generate a users Fave tracks using the Soundcloud widget API, but can't seem to figure out what the iFrame src should be.

Shouldn't either of these work?

```
<iframe class="iframe"
              src="https://soundcloud.com/akovalev" 
              width="100%"
              height="465"
              scrolling="no"
              frameborder="no">
</iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe class="iframe"
              src="https://soundcloud.com/akovalev/likes" 
              width="100%"
              height="465"
              scrolling="no"
              frameborder="no">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is including the SoundCloud site in an iframe, rather than the embedded player. The easiest way to get the right code is to visit the likes page (eg: https://soundcloud.com/akovalev/likes) and click on the share button. In the dialog will be the correct embed code.